# stringstream noshowpoint doesn't work

Tags: c++, stringstream

I'm trying to write 67.5 as 006750 with code below:

```
 float price = 67.5
 stringstream symbol;
 symbol << setfill('0') << setw(6) << fixed << setprecision(2) 
        << noshowpoint << price;
```

but output is 067.50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused. `std::noshowpoint` only eliminates the trailing `.0` on integer floats, for example `60.0` gets outputted as `60`, it doesn't simply remove the point on all numbers.

To get what you want you can do this:

```
float price = 67.5;
std::stringstream symbol;
symbol << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(6) << int(100 * price);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to use noshowpoint to remove the decimal, but if you take a look at the example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/noshowpoint/) you'll see that when pi is printed with noshowpoint, it still retains the decimal probably because you loose your precision without it.

I'd probably just do some string manipulation by hand here, as none of the stringstream options I saw seem to do what you want.